# Understanding DISTINCT vs DISTINCT ON vs Group by

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a query which returns a set of 'records'.
The result is always from the same table, and should always be unique. It has a set of inner joins to filter the rows down to the appropriate subset.
The query is returning roughly 10 columns.
However, I found that it was returning duplicate rows, so I added select distinct to the query, which solved the duplication problem but has significant performance issues.

My understanding is that `select distinct on (records.id), id...` will return the same result in this case, as all duplicates would have the same primary key, and seems to be about twice as fast.

My other tests show that `group by records.id` is even faster again, and seems to do the same thing?

Am I correct that all three of these approaches will always return the same set of single table records?

Also, is there an easy way to compare the results of different approaches to ensure the set is being returned?

Here is my query:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT records.*
  FROM records
  INNER JOIN records parents on parents.path @> records.path
  INNER JOIN record_types ON record_types.id = records.record_type_id
  INNER JOIN user_roles ON user_roles.record_id = parents.id AND user_roles.user_id = _user_id
  INNER JOIN memberships ON memberships.role_id = user_roles.role_id
  INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id = memberships.role_id
  INNER JOIN groups ON memberships.group_id = groups.id AND
                              groups.id = record_types.view_group_id
```

Any individual record can have tree of 'parent' records. This is done using the ltree plugin. Effectively, we are looking to see if the user has a role which is in a group which is defined as the 'view group' for either the current record, or any of the parents. The query is actually a function, and _user_id is being passed in.

Comment: If you're just trying to filter out duplicate rows `DISTINCT ON` seems like the more semantic (and therefore easier to read) approach compared to `GROUP BY`, which should be used with aggregate functions. To compare the results of your queries you can put them in CTEs, join them and check that all column values are equal and all rows have matches. If you're concerned about performance here perhaps you can look into the root cause of the duplicate records: can you include your query in the question?

Comment: @HenryWoody - I've added the query.

Comment: I have a hunch that it is mostly because of the amount of data needed to bring into the memory (or something around that), could you post the postgresql query plan? using `explain analyze` with your query

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only selecting from `records`, you **don't need** `DISTINCT`; the records are already distinct (I presume).

So the *duplicates* you encounter could be caused by all the joins, for instance if more than one role or group membership matches one of your records, the same `record` will be combined with each of these *references*.

---

```
 SELECT *
  FROM records r
  WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM records pa on pa.path @> r.path
         JOIN record_types typ ON typ.id = r.record_type_id
         JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.record_id = pa.id AND ur.user_id = _user_id
         JOIN memberships mem ON mem.role_id = ur.role_id
         JOIN roles ON roles.id = mem.role_id
         JOIN groups gr ON mem.group_id = gr.id AND gr.id = typ.view_group_id
        )
        ;
```